# Related Portfolio Query in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

im using wordpress 3.8.1 and wanna show 5 related portfolio but i dont know how to query.
my codes to register portfolio is

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');
```

`function portfolio_register() {`

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name', "swiftframework"),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name', "swiftframework"),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item', "swiftframework"),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item', "swiftframework"),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio', "swiftframework"),
    'not_found' =>  __('No portfolio items have been added yet', "swiftframework"),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', "swiftframework"),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(  
    'labels' => $labels,  
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-image',
    'rewrite' => false,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('portfolio-category')
   );  

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer

```
$args=array(  
              'tag__in' => $tag_ids,  
              'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),  
              'showposts'=>3,  // Number of related posts that will be shown.  
              'post_type'=> 'portfolio'  
              );  

              $my_query = new wp_query($args);
```

Best